# Помогите! ОшибкаCS1061

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ошибка  CS1061  "Player" не содержит определения "ChangeHealth", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "ChangeHealth", принимающий тип "Player" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).
Player

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ControlType controlType;
    public Joystick joystick;
    public float speed;
    public float health;

    public enum ControlType{PC, Android}

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 moveInput;
    private Vector2 moveVelocity;
    private Animator anim;

    private bool facingRight = true;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        if(controlType == ControlType.PC)
        {
            joystick.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (controlType == ControlType.PC)
        {
            moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        }
        else if (controlType == ControlType.Android)
        {
            moveInput = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);
        }
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;

        if (moveInput.x == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }

        if(!facingRight && moveInput.x > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if(facingRight && moveInput.x < 0)
        {
            Flip() ;
        }
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        }
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
}
```

Bullet

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float lifetime;
    public float distance;
    public int damage;
    public LayerMask whatIsSolid;

    [SerializeField] bool enemyBullet;

    private void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D HitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up, distance, whatIsSolid);
        if(HitInfo.collider != null)
        {
            if (HitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
            {
                HitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(damage);
            }
            if (HitInfo.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                HitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Player>().ChangeHealth(damage);
            }
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: ну... у класса `Player` нет метода `ChangeHealth`, который вы пытаетесь вызвать

Comment: вероятно, вы забыли его добавить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходя из вашего кода, класс `Player` содержит 4 метода:

```
private void Start()
private void Update()
private void FixedUpdate()
private void Flip()
```

В классе `Bullet` в строчке

```
HitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Player>().ChangeHealth(damage);
```

вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `ChangeHealth(int)` у объекта типа `Player`, но такого метода просто нет. Вероятно, стоит его создать. Или хотя бы написать:

```
HitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Player>().health -= damage;
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо!